# Подключиться к My SQL через Entity

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Есть консольное приложение C# которое нужно подключить к объектам на локальной БД, Mysql. В App.config добавил строку подключения :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="OldMysqlConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="User Id=root;Password=root;Host=localhost;Database=custodian; port=3306;Charset=utf8;connection timeout = 15" />
</connectionStrings>
```

В решение добавлены :

> Entity Framework
>
> MySql.Data
>
> MySql.Data.Entity
>
> MySql.Web

Но при работе с мастером моделей EDM добавленной строки нет, отсутствует даже My SQL как источник данных. Вопрос - как подключиться к My sql базе через Entity ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но вы поставили коннектор для MySQL ? https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264 например вот тут описано что и как

Comment: @alexoander Я ADO функциями подключался нормально к БД. Конечно у меня стоит коннектор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу ответ с Англоязычного ресурса, который мне помог, может еще кому то поможет.

SOLUTION! 2017

Install Nuget Package:

Install-Package EntityFramework

Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.9.9

Install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6   - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Changes in Web.Config

```
 <EntityFramework>
```

to:

```
  <EntityFramework codeConfigurationType = "MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

Add (** your information **):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="**YourContextName**" connectionString="server=**xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**;port=3306;user id=**your user**;password=**your password**;database=**your database**" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

сам столкнулся с той же проблемой.
решается установкой вот этой версии MySQL for VS https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вместо *Host=localhost* написать *server=localhost*, а вместо *User Id=root* написать *uid=root*.
В соответствие с [Документацией MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Comment: Вопрос не стоит в том, что строка неправильная, а в том что при создании EDM модели этой строки нет.

Comment: Тогда стоит проверить взаимозависимость между версиями nuget-пакетов EF и MySql.Data.Entity.